# Not run script if window's width is smaller than value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a responsive website, with some jQuery code, of which some is the following:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#D1000C36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D1000C36LPB3_details").show();});
        $("#D1200C36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D1200C36LPB3_details").show();});
        $("#D1-3CA36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D1-3CA36LPB3_details").show();});
        $("#D1-0CA36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D1-0CA36LPB3_details").show();});
        $("#D700S36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D700S36LPB3_details").show();});
        $("#D700S24LMB3").click(function(){$("#D700S24LMB3_details").show();});
    });
</script>
```

All of the `div` elements above (`#D1000C36LPB3_details`, `#D1200C36LPB3_details`, `#D1-3CA36LPB3_details`...) have a CSS `display` property value of `none`, so by default they aren't visible until you click on one of the `div` elements above (`#D1000C36LPB3`, `#D1200C36LPB3`, `#D1-3CA36LPB3`...) and then the corresponding div is displayed.

**However**, when the jQuery script runs, it sets the corresponding `div` `display` value to `block`. When the viewport's/window's width is smaller than say 400 px, I want the script to display them with `position: fixed;`.

### My suggestion

I've figured out I can display them with fixed position using:

```
$("#corresponding_ID").css("display", "fixed");
```

But I still have to not let jQuery run the first script (the one using `.show()`).

Comment: add/remove a class instead and handle it with css. This will allow for it to work even with browser resizing in desktop and tablet/mobile orientation changes.

Comment: Did you find the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Kind of with @connexo 's. The problem is in this question I didn't type **all** my code (you can certainly see that I said in the questions' first paragraph "with some jQuery code, of which some is the following [...]". Now the supplement of connexo's making error with the rest of that jQuery code.

Comment: My answer is the only one that actually answers the question as asked. As  @alej27 is looking for a way to determine browser width with Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set css styles directly this way. As already commented, use e.g. a `.visible` class and let ***css media queries*** decide. Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .visible {
    display: fixed;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .visible {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Then, in your click handler, go as follows:

```
$("#D1000C36LPB3").click(function(){$("#D1000C36LPB3_details").addClass('visible');});
```

Also, if your details containers all follow that naming scheme with affixing `_details` to the `id`, it'd be easier to put all ids in an array and iterate over that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ids = [ "#D1000C36LPB3", "#D1200C36LPB3", "#D1-3CA36LPB3", "#D1-0CA36LPB3", "#D700S36LPB3", "#D700S24LMB3"];
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    $(ids[i]).on('click', function () { $(ids[i]+'_details').addClass('visible'); }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to check for browser width with Jquery:

```
var width = $(window).width(); 
if (width >= 1024) { 
  -- Code to execute here --
}else{
 -- Other code to execute here --
}
```

Then you can adjust the width you are looking and update the >= based on what you want to do.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.